# SmoothHistrogram plot is not smooth

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms

I used the following code to show a small hump near 5000. With R it's fine but for some reason Mathematica draws strange vertical lines. I tried several combinations of ranges. (Data from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijiyF7PimsoNhgj_4m6t0aPgophBzhxa/view?usp=sharing) or [here](https://pastebin.com/ZNZz7vhb).)

```
data3 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ZNZz7vhb"]
data3 = Flatten[data3]
p1 = SmoothHistogram[data3, Automatic, PlotRange -> {{4000, 6000}, {0, 0.0001}}]
```

**R version:**

```r
probcond2 <- scan("f(x y).dat")
data <- data.frame(probcond2)
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=probcond2)) +
  stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,30,100,300,1000,4000,6000), trans="log1p", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 6000)) +facet_zoom(ylim = c(0,800),zoom.size = 0.3,xlim = c(log1p(4300),log1p(6000)),shrink = FALSE)
```

Comment: try a larger bandwidth? e.g. `SmoothHistogram[data3, 100]`

Comment: With *R* it isn't fine.  The default number of points to evaluate the density in *R* is 512.  To match what *Mathematica* does with the same bandwidth you'll need to include `n=5120` (or say 10 times larger than `n=512`) to get the same representation.  You'd be much better off (in *R* and *Mathematica*) to estimate the density of `Log[data3]`.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not sure to understand what you are saying. Even without specifying the number of points I see with R the distribution getting smoother increasing the dimension of the dataset. Changing the bandwidth works but I’m not sure why Mathematica in Auto doesn’t work properly.

Comment: If you say that *R* does it correctly but *Mathematica* does not, you should provide your *R* code (which I assume is only one or two lines of code).

Comment: *Mathematica*'s `SmoothHistogram` matches pretty well with *R*'s `density` function.  I think your issue is matching up *R*'s `density` with what `ggplot2` does with `stat_density`.  If you could explain that difference in the *R* functions in your question, then maybe it would be appropriate to duplicate what `stat_density` does in *Mathematica*.

Comment: `SmoothHistogram[data3, 100, PlotRange -> {{4000, 6000}, All}]`

Answer (score 2):

To show the "bump" around 5,000 I suspect that you might be estimating the probability density with the log of the values.  If so, that makes sense for this set of data.  But you aren't using the `Log` with the *Mathematica* code.

Here's `SmoothHistogram` using the log:

```
ticks = {Log[#], #} & /@ {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000};
SmoothHistogram[Log[data3], Automatic, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
  {ticks, {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}},
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["Probability density", Bold, 18], ""},
    {Style["Log[x]", Bold, 18], Style["x", Bold, 18]}}, AxesOrigin -> {-2.5, 0}]
```

[image: Probability density of log(x)]

Using *R*:

```
plot(density(log(x)), type="l")
```

[image: Probability density of log(x) using R]

The figures are essentially identical.